# How do I create a button in a block?

Tags: drupal, button, drupal-7

Using Drupal 7, I tried putting the following into the block body with no success.

```
<form action="http://mysite.com/request">
    <p class="rtecenter"><input type="button" value="Click Me!" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Make sure you're using the correct Text Format filter that isn't filtering out your tags.

Comment: Thanks, but using "full html" with no limits on tags

Comment: What's the resulting output when you render/place the block on a page?

Comment: You need to confirm what "no success" means: that it isn't appearing at all, that it isn't submitting the form or something else. A "button" input won't submit the form its contained within; for that you need a "submit" input.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal has its on way for creating and handling forms. You can take a look at [webform module](http://drupal.org/project/webform).

Or you can create your custom form using: [hook_block_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7)(), [hook_block_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7)() and don't forget to take a look at [drupal form API quick-start guide](http://drupal.org/node/751826).

Hope this helps... Muhammad.